# Типовой объект (эталон)

Tags: c#

Не смог сформулировать заголовок, попробую объяснить.
По сети получаю данные, среди данный есть id устройства.
Нужно по этому id создать объект. При чем, зная id, я понимаю что за устройство, какие значения свойств он имеет.
Например, 
id = 1: name = "device1", inputs = 3

т.е. у меня нарисовывается коллекция типовых объектов из которых нужно брать значения свойств для вновь создаваемых объектов.

Сейчас у меня есть класс Device, в нем статический список с типовыми Device'ми.
При создании объекта, я нахожу по id  в этом списке нужные значения свойств.

Как лучше делать подобную вещь?

Comment: Не проще ли держать не множество типовых объектов, а множество типовых свойств, и из них собирать новый ?

Comment: Или что бы было проще множество объектов поделить на подмножества и иметь какое либо дерево чтобы отображать в UI

Comment: не знаю, поэтому и спрашиваю. Просто описание типовых свойств требует своего типа, ведь этих свойств у меня 4.

Comment: ну или словарь со свойствами, где ключом будет id устройства

Comment: Только свойства разных типов
{1: {name:"device1", inputs: 3, outputs: 2}, 2: {...} }
Во внутреннем есть пары string:string, а есть пары string:int

Comment: не проще ли просто вводить инты и стринги? это не такие и типовые свойства, или просто дропбоксом выводить значения интов от 1 до N и у name иметь просто prefix + число от 0 до N

Comment: Хранить все типовые девайсы в объекте девайса нелогично. Лучше фабрику создать.

Comment: ParanoidPanda, мне нужно на экран вывести адекватное название устройства, device1 - это просто пример.

Comment: Я думаю это можно реализовать перечислением над структурой.

Comment: Вот еще нечто подобное встретил. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250915/enum-with-object-or-a-dictionary-like-enum может так же сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы создал что-то вроде такого:

```
class DeviceFactory
{
     public static Device CreateDevice(int deviceId)
     {
           switch (deviceID)
           {
               case 1:
                  return new Deivce(){id = deviceId, name="name1", inputs=3};
               case 2:
                  return new Deivce(){id = deviceId, name="name2", inputs=5};
               case 3:
                  return new Deivce(){id = deviceId, name="name3", inputs=2};
               default:
                  return new Deivce();
           }
     }
}
```

Comment: ну или как вариант что то типа [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39488191/factory-class-is-not-supporting-solid-principle/39488823#39488823)

Comment: выглядит хорошо. Помимо постоянных свойств, есть значения которые тоже получаю по сети, например, ip. Если сделаю так:
public static Device CreateDevice(int deviceId, Ip ipAddress)
...
case 1:
                  return new Deivce(){id = deviceId, name="name1", inputs=3, ip = ipAddress};
Нормально?

Comment: @ДмитрийСуворов вполне, можно даже использовать опциональный параметр по типу `Ip ipAdress = null`

Comment: @tym32167 тоже сначала подумал о подобной реализации, но по описанию показалось, что девайсы имеют одинаковое поведение (раз уж класс у них один) и в таком случае это имеет мало смысла

Comment: хмм, если девайс - тип один, то да, смысла нет. В таком случае даже фабрика по идее не нужна - можно просто передавать параметры в конструктор

Comment: @yolosora решение мне нравится. Но кажется это хард-код. Думаю считывать эти свойства из БД или файла, чтобы в дальнейшем не исправляя программу можно было добавить новых устройств и их свойства изменить.